# Shared Git Repository on Windows File Server (Fail)

Tags: git, repository, shared, git-bare

Before anyone jumps in and refers me to a prior post, let me say, I've gone through all of them with no success.

As the title says, I'm trying to setup a shared git repository on a Windows file server using local path (e.g. `s:\SharedProjects\foo`), where each developer has a local repository (e.g. `c:\MyProjects\foo`).

So far I've managed to create / clone the repository, but I can't push back changes from local user to shared dir.  I've tried setting it as `--bare` repository, I've tried setting `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`, but I always different problems.

Setting the repo as bare, all of the git-dir files (`.git/*`) reside immediately below my root directory (`s:\SharedProjects\foo\[config, HEAD, ..*]`), and does not allow me to perform other repository tasks such as `git ls-files` or `git status`, saying these operations must be made in the working directory.

The I set the working directory above my bare repository (e.g. `\SharedProjects\bar`), and I can't perform any operations on that because it doesn't recognize a git repository :|

I'm going crazy here.. I've been trying every which way I can to set the `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`, setting my repository as `--bare --share=everybody`..  I lost track of where I'm at now!

Can someone please give specific step by step instructions on crating a repository (on a Windows file share) that will allow for central repository management as well as local repository push / pull operations?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**To setup your 'Remote' Repo**

- Open a Git bash window
- type `cd s:/SharedProjects/foo`
- type `git init --bare`

**To Setup your local repo**

- type `cd c:/MyProjects/`
- type `git clone s:\SharedProjects\foo foo`
- do all of your commits here locally
- push commits to your shared repo

Answer (score 0):

We do this at for all our projects here.  We always init with `git init --bare --shared` (You have --share, possibly just a typo in your post, but worth double checking)

If you still can't get it working, post the push command you are using and the results.

Answer (score 0):

I've been unable to get this to work in cygwin git.

I got it to work by installing the "Git for Windows" from https://git-scm.com/download/win and using that environment rather than the cygwin one.